# If I got a good puzzle, can I post it on Meta if I am question-limited?

Tags: support, asking-questions, meta

Thanks to some advice from my previous meta posts, I finally came up with a good puzzle.

As we all know, the question limit isn't removable thanks to the downvotes, and can only be cleared if we put the scores back to 0. Now, this is a problem for me (if not anyone else), since I finally came up with a good puzzle, and I can't post it now.

So I thought of putting it in meta first, but then realized the off-topic situation. So I decided to make this question instead for verification.

If I can't fix my scores, where can I post my puzzle first? Apart from the off-topic case, are there other reasons why I should (not) post the puzzle on Meta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. This site is for questions [about Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), not for puzzles themselves. If you're question-banned on the main site, we (or the moderators) can't even migrate it to where it belongs. You'll have to wait until you're out of your question ban until you can post the puzzle.

Comment: "Question-banned"? No, I said question limited, not ban.

Comment: The terminology around this stuff is a bit inconsistent. E.g., the moderators' view of your user info _does_ use the term "question ban" for the state you're currently in. The good news is that you'll be out of it in a few days.